# Reassign value to variables

Tags: bash

I have the function below. I declare local variable.  It is not clear for me what happens if I change the variable value later in the code.

The same local variable get a new value, or a global variable is declared ?

```
function create_node() { 

  local opt="3"
  .....
  opt=4
  ....
  opt=6
}
```

My concern is that, bash by default declare global variables, and second time not to create a global variable with the same name.

Comment: `opt` will remain local inside your function body.

Comment: @axiac I edited, value I wanted to say

Comment: From `bash` man page `When local is used within a function, it causes the variable name to have a visible scope restricted to that function and its children.`